# Querying String Columns as Numeric

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing for multiple SQLServer database versions, so I cannot use TRY_CONVERT, as SQLSERVER 2008 R2 must be supported.

I have several tables that share the same set values, many of which are numeric, but some of which are not. (Yuck, bad design decision, but legacy code that is very hard to change.)

I need to get a list of all of the unique values that are numeric *as integers* that are within a certain range.

So I have SQL that looks sort of like this:

```
SELECT C1, C2_AS_INT (
  SELECT C1, CAST( LTRIM(RTRIM(C2)) AS INT ) AS C2_AS_INT FROM T1 WHERE ISNUMERIC(C2) = 1 --We are accepting of any problems with ISNUMERIC
  UNION
  SELECT C1, CAST( LTRIM(RTRIM(C2)) AS INT ) AS C2_AS_INT FROM T2 WHERE ISNUMERIC(C2) = 1
) AS C2_AS_INT_QUERY
```

This is fine and it works (although I'm unsure of what datatype C2_AS_INT is in the outer query.)

However, when I add a where-clause to it, I'm getting an error that a failure occurs due to converting from an nvarchar to an int.

```
SELECT C1, C2_AS_INT (
  SELECT C1, CAST( LTRIM(RTRIM(C2)) AS INT ) AS C2_AS_INT_INNER FROM T1 WHERE ISNUMERIC(C2) = 1 --We are accepting of any problems with ISNUMERIC
  UNION
  SELECT C1, CAST( LTRIM(RTRIM(C2)) AS INT ) AS C2_AS_INT_INNER FROM T2 WHERE ISNUMERIC(C2) = 1
) AS C2_AS_INT_QUERY
WHERE C2_AS_INT >= 1
```

It seems like it is adding the WHERE clause to the inner queries instead of the outer query which I would have suspected should have been cast to an INT.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, I was able to take the original query into a Table-Valued function. Then I could apply the where clause as expected to the result of the UDF.

While I'm marking this as the accepted answer, I'm still interested in knowing if there's a technique that can be applied at the query level to get this to work.